# How can Sakamoto talk?

Tags: nichijou

In a clip of *Nichijou* that I saw, Sakamoto the cat is seen being able to talk, and appears to be quite intelligent. (His lips never move, but he does speak.)

[image: Sakamoto playing with an eraser]

How is Sakamoto able to do this? Are other cats able to as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The red scarf that Sakamoto wears allows him to talk. The scarf was "invented" by another character in the series - Hakase (which means Professor).

[image: Screenshot of Hakase announcing her scarf invention]

In another episode, a crow is wearing the scarf and can also talk.

[image: Screenshot of Crow talking thanks to the scarf]

Comment: Also, once the scarf is taken off, the previous wearer goes back to making animal noises again, rather than just having worn it once and being able to talk.

Comment: Are the mechanics of the scarf ever explained? Or is it just a "magic" awesome thing? xD

Comment: @Eric: Like how Nano comes to life, we can only take this as "some awesome invention that is casually made".

Comment: @Eric There are a good amount of inventions in the show that aren't explained. Hakase is just a genius little scientist (so it's not really magic, just unexplained extraordinary science).